# Product Page View: How can I display bundled items using multiple columns?

Tags: bundled-product, product-page

I have created a bundled product called 'Top Brass Buffet'. There are 4 Bundled Items: Entree1 SideDish1 Entree2 SideDish2 
Each Entree can be chosen from 8 items ( radio buttons ) and each Side Dish can be chosen from 8 items ( radio buttons )

When viewing the product page, all the bundled items are listed below each other. I have also installed this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/display-bundle-product-s-bundled-items-images-2.html

This creates a long page for the user. I would like to create 4 columns instead (larger heading print would be great too ) - 
Thanks in advance - please ask for more info if I have been unclear in my explanation / request

Here's the product page - thanks again !!
http://chefchipper.com/index.php/silver-service/tb-buffet.html/

Answer (score 1):

See if the module have some option to select who many item you want per line, now are 3, you need to select 4, then you need some css.

.options-list.robbie-bundle-options > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26%;
}